# C++ ostream referencing

Tags: c++, reference, ostream

Why does line 4 in the following print a memory address instead of the original string printed by line 2, and how do I correct this? Many thanks.

```
std::stringstream os (std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
std::cout << result->studentId;
os << result->studentId;
std::cout << &os << std::endl;
```

Comment: It's the same with or without "&" on line 4 in front of "os".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `str()` function to get the underlying string:

```
std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
```

For future reference here's [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) on `std::stringstream`, which contains every member function.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking  at cplusplus.com and stdcxx.apache.org but couldn't find the str(). The reference you pointed is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

remove `&` operator

```
std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
```